# Passing column list names and table name as arguments to sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to pass column-list and table name as arguments to statement (query) mentioned in sp_executesql.

For column names it is displaying the column names n numbers of times and not the data corresponding to that column. And for table name, it is not allowing it as input all together.

Is there a way?

```
declare @query nvarchar(max) = N'select @c from @t';
declare @col nchar(1) = 'x';
declare @table nchar(5) = 'sch.a'
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@c nchar(1)', N'@t nchar(5)', @c=@col, @t=@table;
```

Comment: The only way is dynamic SQL, i.e. build your SQL statement in a string (NVARCHAR(X)) and pass it to sp_executesql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot pass column name as parameter to sp\_executesql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335319/cannot-pass-column-name-as-parameter-to-sp-executesql)

Comment: be careful...you will be opening yourself up to SQL injection dependent on how the parameters are established

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only parameterize constant values in SQL queries.  This means that you cannot parameterize column names, table names, schema names, database names, functions, and operators.

Hence, you cannot do what you want using parameters.  You have to munge the query string:

```
declare @query nvarchar(max) = N'select @c from @t';
declare @col nchar(1) = 'x';
declare @table nchar(5) = 'sch.a'

set @query = replace(replace(@query, '@c', @col), '@t', @table);

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Note:  You should really use `quotename()` on the identifiers, to handle unexpected characters.  Also, there is no reason to declare the variables as `nchar()`.  Just use `nvarchar(255)` or something like that.

This may seem like an arcane restriction, but there is a pretty good reason.  One benefit of using dynamic SQL is that the query plan is cached.  This allows the same plan to be used each time the query is compiled, saving on the compilation time.  Clearly, the table needs to be known for the query to be compiled.  It may be less clear that the columns need to be known, but they are also used for index selection.